# align word wrap text in android button

Tags: android-layout, android, android-button

How can I align wraped text in a button ?

this is my button layout :

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttontest"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:background="@color/white_botton"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/message_button"
     android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
     android:text="Testing newline"
     android:textSize="16sp" />
```

this is how it looks :

[image]

I want the new line to be aligned with the first line.

( If I try with a textview I dont have this issue )

Comment: seems that there is no space on right side hence it is breaking and shwoing in new line

Comment: its ok that it showing in new line, but its not aligned with first line

Answer (score 2):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttontest"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/message_button"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="Testing newline"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

[image: Check this image]

You can set width according to your need.
My image size isnt perfect using your image will be fine I guess

Comment: The 0dp width + wrap_content height + 1 weight did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
```

and Check

hope it will help you

Comment: but I do want the text left aligned ( and even if I remove the gravity the lines are unaligned )

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `android:drawablePadding` to get some space between the icon and the text.

Comment: this adds padding for the first row and the second one also, and they remain unaligned

Comment: I tried your example (without the background and another icon) and could not reproduce the behaviour. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is something wrong somewhere else in my code, in a new clean project the alignment works. thank you for all your answers.